# NPM module system-sleep sleeps forever

Tags: node.js, npm

My code is very simple. But only 0 is printed. sleep sleeps forever :( What is the mistake I am failing to notice???

```
import sleep from 'system-sleep';
function starti()
{
    for (var y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        console.log(y);
        sleep(1000);
    }
}

starti()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the '**system-sleep**' library, this could happen for two reasons:

1. you're using this as es-module, I've tried both type (common-js en es-module) and the common-js type work properly ( `var sleep = require('system-sleep')` )
2. you're using node >= 14, that seems to [broke the library](https://github.com/jochemstoel/nodejs-system-sleep/issues/20) :(

Since you're not doing nothing wrong, I suggest you to change the library